# How to increment a value using onClick in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator

I have a button when pressed onClick triggers `LikeComment` which posts the like to a DataBase using the current comment id and user who posted the comment.

```
    <button className="btn" onClick={LikeComment(comment_id, user_id)}>
      <div className="text">
        <i className="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        <p>{comment_likes.length}</p>
      </div>
    </button>
```

What would be the best way to increment `comment_likes.length` when ever the button is pressed. Right now my problem is that the value only updates when page refreshes.

I have tried to do this, but It doesn't work as intended

```
<p>{comment_likes.length && LikeComment ? (comment_likes.length+1) : (comment_likes.length)}</p>
```

I want to achieve this by detecting when LikeComment is pressed to increment the original value by 1.

Any tips to tackle this would be appreciated..

Comment: You could update the local state, or trigger a refetch of the updated DB data. Can you update your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that includes all the relevant code?

Comment: The useState hook will provide a variable, and a function to set its value. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html You can include this variable in your rendered JSX and it will update whenever the value is updated. I'd suggest you try an intro to react tutorial as well, this is fairly basic react. https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html#learn-react

Comment: @nlta I have tried useState but I get a `Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.` Since the button is enclosed inside a map function to display the comments.

Comment: Post all the code for that component. You've got some other bug.

Comment: where does `comment_likes` come from? There's not enough information in your question to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to store the current like amount in the local state of the component. This way you can just display the current amount of likes and react will automatically update the display if you change the `buttonLikes` amount.

`const [buttonLikes, setButtonLikes] = useState(comment_likes)`

Then you'll need an event handler which will increment the like amount and post your changes to the DB

```js
    const handleClickLikeButton = (comment_id, user_id) => {
        setButtonLikes((prevValue) => prevValue + 1)
        LikeComment(comment_id, user_id)
    }
```

Now your display logic will look like this

```html
   <button className="btn" onClick={handleButtonLike(comment_id, user_id)}>
      <div className="text">
        <i className="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        <p>{buttonLikes}</p>
      </div>
    </button>
```

Comment: This helped me, thanks! `setButtonLikes((prevValue) => prevValue + 1)` worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
const [likesCount, setlikesCount] = useState(0)
```

and then create a function like this :

```
 const callapiforlike=(comment_id, user_id){
   // call some api
  }
 const handleLikeCountIncrement= (comment_id, user_id) => {
        setlikesCount(likesCount + 1)
        callapiforlike(comment_id, user_id)

    }
```

and for like button

```
<button className="btn" onClick={handleLikeCountIncrement(comment_id, user_id)}>
      <div className="text">
        <i className="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
        <p>{likesCount}</p>
      </div>
    </button>
```